# ReactJS How to toggle elements to hide or show

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am very new to React and the ES6 syntax I have a chat widget that i want to toggle to show and hide as i click the header,and I have already implemented an onClick handler, but in terms of the logic I am having trouble finding a similar implementation online. this is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import chat from './styles.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ChatWidget extends Component {

  handleClick(event) {
    console.log("Hide or unhide chat body")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={chat.container}>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
             className={chat.header}>
          <span className={chat.name}>Idol</span>
        </div>
        <div className={chat.body}>
          This is the Body of the chat
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.activeUser
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatWidget);
```

Answer (score 1):

It could look like this:

```
class ChatWidget extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showChat: true
    };
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      showChat: !this.state.showChat
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={chat.container}>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
             className={chat.header}>
          <span className={chat.name}>Idol</span>
        </div>
        {this.state.showChat && 
         (<div className={chat.body}>
          This is the Body of the chat
         </div>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.activeUser
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatWidget);
```

But there are different approaches for conditional rendering.
See documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `state` variable that will store the current state, whether to show the body or not. On the basis of that variable render the body of the Chart, that is called `conditional rendering`.

Check this:

```
class ChatWidget extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={isShowBody: true} 
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={chat.container}>
                <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className={chat.header}>
                  <span className={chat.name}>Idol</span>
                </div>
                {this.state.isShowBody ? 
                    <div className={chat.body}>
                        This is the Body of the chat
                    </div>
                : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a css class

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And dynamically toggle that class on your `<div class={chat.body}`.

So add an id to the div so it's easier to grab.

```
<div class={chat.body} id='chat-body'>
  ...
</div>
```

And inside your `handleClick` method

```
handleClick(event) {
  let chat = document.getElementById("chat-body");

  chat-body.classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

Comment: this is just a js approach, but definitly not a good one for react!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example, it has comments on the lines so you know what each line is doing.

Consider that adding a `hidden` class to the component will not unmount it, it will just hide it from the DOM

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import chat from './styles.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ChatWidget extends Component {
  // You need state to update the view
  state = {
    show: false
  }

  toggleBody() {
    // You can pass true or false to this function to show or hide the body
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  }

  render() {
    {/* Take the show property from the state */}
    const {show} = this.state
    return (
      <div className={chat.container}>
        <div onClick={this.toggleBody.bind(this)} className={chat.header}>
          <span className={chat.name}>Idol</span>
        </div>
        {/* Add the class hidden to the body if show is false (you should create the hidden class in CSS) */}
        <div className={`${chat.body} ${show ? '' : 'hidden'}`}>
          This is the Body of the chat
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.activeUser
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatWidget);
```